# Unity OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my Player to collide with the object capsule. 
This action should destroy the capsule and add a speed value of 10 to the player.

But this code is not working :

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
public KeyCode moveL;
public KeyCode moveR;

public float horizontal = 0;
public int laneNum = 2;
public string controllocked = "n";

public float speed;

void Update ()
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(horizontal, GM.verticalVelocity, speed);

    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(moveL)) && (laneNum > 1) && (controllocked == "n"))
    {
        horizontal = -2;
        StartCoroutine(StopSlide());
        laneNum = laneNum - 1;
        controllocked = "y";
    }
    else if ((Input.GetKeyDown(moveR)) && (laneNum < 3) && (controllocked =="n"))
    {
        horizontal = 2;
        laneNum = laneNum + 1;
        StartCoroutine(StopSlide());
        controllocked = "y";
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "lethal")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Capsule")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        speed = 10;   
    }
}

IEnumerator StopSlide()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
    horizontal = 0;
    controllocked = "n";
}
```

What I've tried so far is `speed += 10` and `speed++` neither works.

Comment: Is Update() called when changing the speed?

Comment: Okay you could debug this easy by doing this 1st.) replace `speed=10;` to this `speed+=10;` then try to put a `Debug.Log("The speed now is: " + speed);` put this below of the `speed+=10` and come back here

Comment: I didn't want to update every frame or do I have to do that? I just want add speed once. And I put debug.log under update coudn't do it under OnTriggerEnter......what is going on ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at first try to check your player, What collider type that you use in the player? 
Make sure you check trigger in the collider component and add rigidbody into it.
The capsule object must have rigidbody on it.
Hope it help.
Use OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) if you want to use triggerenter. Collision enter work if trigger is not checked

Comment: you're welcome, don't worry about that. Sometimes I forgot about that too